# sortable data from table2 to table1

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I just want the user has an option to move items from the lower table(#sortable2) to the upper table (#sortable1).

I think it's related to `{'connectWith':'.connectedSortable',`

I tried: `{'connectWith':'#sortable1, .connectedSortable',` but it doesn't work..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('#sortable1, #sortable2')
 .sortable(
 {'connectWith':'.connectedSortable',
 'dropOnEmpty':true,
 'scroll':true,
  items: "li:not(.emptyMessage)",
  receive: function(event, ui) {
         //hide empty message on receiver
         $('li.emptyMessage', this).hide();

         //show empty message on sender if applicable
         if($('li:not(.emptyMessage)', ui.sender).length == 0){
             $('li.emptyMessage', ui.sender).show();
         } else {
             $('li.emptyMessage', ui.sender).hide();
         }            
     }

  });
});
```

this is my `index.html.erb`:

```
<html>
  <body>


   <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable"> 


    <% @tasks_worker_todo.each do |task| %>
          <li class="ui-state-default">
            <%= best_in_place task, :done, :classes => 'highlight_on_success', type: :checkbox, collection: %w[No Yes] %> | 
            <%= task.admin_mail %> | 
            <%= task.task %>
          </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>


  <br><br>

  <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <% @tasks_worker_done.each do |task| %>
          <li class="ui-state-highlight">
             <%= best_in_place task, :done,:classes => 'highlight_on_success', type: :checkbox, collection: %w[No Yes] %> | 
             <%= task.admin_mail %> | 
             <%= task.task %>
          </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>


</body>
</html>
```

please help.

Comment: show markup used. Not sure why you reference `LI` when working with tables

Comment: @charlietfl, thank you.. I use this example: http://jsfiddle.net/8TCxY/

Comment: what doesn't work? If I empty a list the message shows up

Comment: @charlietfl, now you can move "items" from first table to the second table, and from the second table to the first table. I want there is only option to move items from the second table to the first table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per the docs `connectWith` is a one-way relationship.

Try this:

```
'connectWith':'#sortable1'
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8TCxY/41/